# Disable dragging in WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, webview

I'm building a Cocoa application and I need to disable the user from dragging an image around, eg. on Google.com you can hold your mouse down on the google logo and drag/drop it on to your desktop. Any ideas how to remove this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

After your webview has finished loading do this:

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *javascriptString = @"document.body.setAttribute('ondragstart','return false')";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```

**Swift**

```
let javascriptString = "document.body.setAttribute('ondragstart','return false')"
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascriptString)
```

That should do the trick.